# Cannot Access Dashboard.Folder.DeveloperName?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

While saving the below code, following error occurs:

> Variable does not exist: DeveloperName

```
List<Dashboard> listAllDashboards = [SELECT DeveloperName,Type,FolderName,Folder.DeveoperName FROM Dashboard];
for(Dashboard d1 : listAllDashboards){
 System.debug(d1.Folder.DeveloperName);
}
```

Comment: In your query above you have `DeveoperName` instead of `DeveloperName`. Is that how you wrote it in your org or is it a transcription error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Folder` field on `Dashboard` object behaves like polymorphic field, that is why before referecing field with dot notation there is a need to cast object to specific type. That means, that the following code works:

```
List<Dashboard> listAllDashboards = [
    select DeveloperName, Type, FolderName, FolderId, Folder.DeveloperName
    from Dashboard
    ];
for(Dashboard d1 : listAllDashboards){
    System.debug(((Folder)d1.Folder).DeveloperName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Weird that we cannot access `Folder.DeveloperName` directly in Dashboard object.

As an alternative you can do it by [Accessing sObject Fields Through Relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_field_relationships.htm):

```
for(Dashboard d: [SELECT DeveloperName,Type,FolderName, 
    Folder.DeveloperName FROM Dashboard]) {
    Folder f = d.Folder;
    System.debug('f: ' + f.DeveloperName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a bug in Salesforce but you can use the sObject method get to retrieve the field by name (there was also a typo on your query):

```
List<Dashboard> listAllDashboards = [SELECT 
DeveloperName,Type,FolderName,Folder.DeveloperName FROM Dashboard];

for(Dashboard d1 : listAllDashboards){
  System.debug(d1.Folder.get('DeveloperName'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Dashboard> listAllDashboards = [SELECT 
DeveloperName,Type,FolderName,Folder.Name FROM Dashboard];
for(Dashboard d1 : listAllDashboards){
System.debug(d1.Folder.Name);
}
```

Please do something like this

Comment: -1 as OP wants to access `DeveloperName` not `Name`